# javascript: remove/add class function

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

i found a very simple javascript function for a slideshow ([here](https://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-simple-javascript-slideshow-without-jquery/)). 
It works perfectly, but i want to change something about the control buttons. Right now, the play/pause button displays it's own name, like this:

```
<button class="controls" id="pause">Pause</button>
```

The javascript is set to run a function called `pauseSlideshow` under certain circumstances which not only pauses/resumes the slideshow, but also changes the displayed content of the button from "pause" to "play":

```
var playing = true;
var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

function pauseSlideshow() {
    pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
    playing = false;
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
}
```

now, what i want to do is to leave the button empty and work width background images, and to do that i planned to do a simple class swap whenever the `pauseSlideshow` function is triggered. So, first i added a class called `pause` to the button with the desired background image set in the style:

```
<button class="controls pause" id="pause"></button>
```

and next i was going to do something like this:

```
var playing = true;
var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

function pauseSlideshow() {
    pauseButton.removeClass('pause');
    pauseButton.addClass('play');
    playing = false;
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
}
```

(where `play` is another class with a different background image). Sufficient to say, as soon as `pauseSlideshow` runs, the function crashes. I'm writing something wrong or in the wrong place, but i know that the approach is viable.

please, can anybody point out the error?

**EDIT:**

> Use $(pauseButton).removeClass('pause'); and
>   $(pauseButton).addClass('play');. addClass and removeCalss are jQuery
>   methods. And you need to add jQuery reference too. – user3698428
>
> document.getElementById("pause") does not return a jQuery element.
>   .removeClass() and .addClass() are jQuery functions. So basically you
>   are trying to call jQuery functions on a non-jQuery element and it's
>   throwing an error. Change it to var pauseButton = $("#pause"); or
>   $(pauseButton).removeClass(...); $(pauseButton).addClass(...);

when i try either way, console returns: *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*

Comment: Use $(pauseButton).removeClass('pause'); and $(pauseButton).addClass('play');. addClass and removeCalss are jQuery methods. And you need to add jQuery reference too.

Comment: `document.getElementById("pause")` does not return a jQuery element. `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` are jQuery functions. So basically you are trying to call jQuery functions on a non-jQuery element and it's throwing an error. Change it to `var pauseButton = $("#pause");` or `$(pauseButton).removeClass(...); $(pauseButton).addClass(...);`

Comment: Did you [check your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log#t=201610171959284503658) You're trying to use jQuery methods on regular elements.

Answer (score 2):

When working in pure javascript, you should use this to add or remove class:

```
pauseButton.classList.remove('pause');
pauseButton.classList.add('play');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList